# Is there a way to create a searchable picklist in a visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component

I have a picklist field and I was wondering if there is a way to add a searchbox at the top of the picklist where we enter a picklist value and it searches through the picklist to find the values. **Something like this:**

[image]

Comment: When I was presented with the same problem I ended up using a custom lookup component, like this one: http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeLookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard component/way available to do this. You need to write your custom code to achieve it.

First you can use the [dataList](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) tag to achieve it.

```
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
```

[image]

Or you can use third part JS like [Select2.](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)

Comment: I used the Select2 library. Works really well. Thank You!

Comment: can you guide me please?

Comment: i tried but dropdown options is not displaying

Comment: @nubie make sure you are using HTML in your VF.

Comment: Thanks @TusharSharma I fixed it issue in js library