# Searchable pick-list in Lightning Component?

Tags: picklist, search, lightning-components

I am trying to implement the searchable pick-list in lightning component. I followed [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248293/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-searchable-picklist-in-a-visualforce-page) to implement with help of external jQuery select2. Does any one suggest me the best way of implementing searchable picklist in lightning component.

**xxx.cmp**

```
<aura:component access="global">
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.select2}" />
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.select2}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.loadJquery}" />
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="xx">xx</option>
        <option value="yy">yy</option>
        <option value="zz">zz</option>
        <option value="rr">rr</option>
        <option value="tt">tt</option>
        <option value="mm">mm</option>
    </select>
</aura:component>
```

**xxx.js**

```
({
    loadJquery : function(component, event, helper) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
        });
    }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like jquery issue. This can be resolved by

1. Use jquery version https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js
2. Use Select2 library from https://github.com/select2/select2/archive/4.0.3.zip

Zip both library and upload as single static resource. You can also upload separately.

**Aura component code will be**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.select2+ '/select2.min.css'}"
                   scripts="{!join(',',$Resource.select2 + '/jquery-2.2.4.min.js', $Resource.select2 + '/select2.min.js')}"
          afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.loadJquery}"/>

    <select name="state" class="select2Class" style="width:100%">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="xx">xx</option>
        <option value="yy">yy</option>
        <option value="zz">zz</option>
        <option value="rr">rr</option>
        <option value="tt">tt</option>
        <option value="mm">mm</option>
    </select>
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller**

```
({
    loadJquery : function(component, event, helper) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $(".select2Class").select2({
               placeholder: "Select Multiple values"
           });
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: the issue is sometime it's not working @Dhanik

Comment: If i need to call doinit method. which is the best way to do this from component `<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>` or from loadjquery method. `var a = component.get('c.doinit'); $A.enqueueAction(a);`

Comment: If you need to call any method after your JS loaded then afterScriptsLoaded method is best other wise you can use aura:handler for init.

Comment: Hi @Dhanik Lal Sahni  , Everything is working fine but if i click pick-list it's taking some time to display the drop-down. it's possible to make it faster as soon as i click the pick-list it should display the drop down